# Coverting an index in a string to an int

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, char, type-conversion

I want to convert an index in a string to an int in order to populate a 2D array of type `int`.

```
string s = "1 2 3";
a[0][0] = s.at(0);
```

I want `a[0][0]` to store the int value 1, but right now it's storing 49 with this method (which I am assuming is the direct conversion).

I have tried `atoi`, `stoi`, and `static_cast`, but I was getting a conversion error.

Comment: `stoi` should work. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: What is "an index in a string"?

Comment: this is the error I am getting: "error: call of overloaded ‘stoi(char&)’ is ambiguous"

Comment: By "index in a string" I mean a value at a certain index like s.at(0), which would be "1"

Comment: OK, if you consider the string as a kind of array of `char`, it would be an "element of a string".

Comment: *"but I was getting a conversion error"* .is not a good error description. **Copy and paste the error message** into the question please.

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
a[0][0] = s.at(0);
```

you are assigning the value of the character `'1'` to `a[0][0]`, which is represented by the integral value of 49 in ASCII encoding.

If you are certain that there is only one digit, you can use

```
a[0][0] = s.at(0) - '0';
```

You can use a more flexible strategy.

```
std::istringstream str(s);
str >> a[0][0];
```

Answer (score -2):

*Gave wrong answer before:*

This should work:

```
using namespace std; 
int main ()
{
  string str ("3");
  int i =  str.at(i) - 48;
  cout << i <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While your answer is correct now, it's not a great one though.

Comment: You are right, guy above me had a better answer XD.
It is because of ascii encoding.

Comment: `int i =  str.at(i) - '0';` would be more readable, and not relying on an ASCII charset.